# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/context/CurrentSessionContext

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am stuck with below error:-
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/context/CurrentSessionContext
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)

I am using spring core-3.2.16.RELEASE and hibernate 3.0.5 jar

Answer (score 0):

Class `org/hibernate/context/CurrentSessionContext` introduced to `hibernate` in version 3.2.0 and up.

Maybe update your project dependency or change the spring configuration.